# parse xlsx file with date columns as numbers to STRING or proper timestamp date in javascript

Tags: node.js, excel, sequelize.js, openxlsx, js-xlsx

I'm using an npm package called xlsx from this repo:

https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs

I am running with the option of cellDates: true but still my output is a number format.  Anybody know how to adapt my code to get my date columns parsed as timestamp format or convert the number to a date as a string which also seems to work when I do it manually in the excel file.

Appreciate the help!

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx')

const excelToObjArr = (filePath) => {
  const obj = xlsx.parse(filePath, { 'type': type, cellDates: true }); // parses a file
  const data = obj[0].data;
  
  let dataObjects = [];
  let tableAttrs = data[0];
  
  for(let i=1; i < data.length; i++){
    let newObj = {};
    for(let j=0; j < tableAttrs.length; j++){
      newObj[tableAttrs[j]] = data[i][j];
    }
    dataObjects.push(newObj);
  }
  
  return dataObjects;
};

module.exports = excelToObjArr;
```